# What is the <module>/release/output.json generated by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-studio-3.0

I recently noticed a new file generated at `<module>/release/output.json` by Android Studio 3 Canary 1 each time I run `Build` -> `Generate Signed APK...`, which has contents that look like following.

Can anyone confirm seeing this behavior as well? Or is it due to some local configuration on my laptop?

And can anyone explain the purpose of this file? Is it safe to add to `.gitignore`?

```
[{
  "outputType": {
    "type": "APK"
  },
  "apkInfo": {
    "type": "MAIN",
    "splits": [],
    "versionCode": 32
  },
  "outputFile": {
    "path": "/path/to/the/generated/release/filename.apk"
  },
  "properties": {
    "packageId": "com.example.android",
    "split": ""
  }
}]
```

Comment: Normal configuration, you can use e.g.: putting on a server, checking from an older version of your app if there is an update and notify the user, or display on a website current version etc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Android studio 3.0 is responsible for this file. You don't need to worry about the output.json file.

Let me explain this to you:

For older versions, what Android Studio did was generate a signed APK and put it in the "output" folder. Even If you had multiple flavour dimensions for your APK, all of them could be located at the same directory, which was the output folder. From the latest release of Android Studio 3.0 (canary and stable), they have organized this file structure. For every flavour dimension, whenever you sign an APK, it will have a separate folder with a corresponding output.json file in it. This file is actually nothing but a description of the source APK. As you can see, the file you shared here is describing the released APK.

Comment: so there is no way to disable this folder and file generation and have all flavor APKs saved to the output folder?

Comment: I still doesn't  know how to disable output.json . but every flavoured signed apk will have separate folder with  the flavour name on it . In past all apks were generated and placed in output folder @chitgoks

Comment: yes you are correct. i find it annoying though why they do not have an option to have it all placed in the output folder. I liked its behavior in < v3.

Comment: I seriously want to disable it.

Answer (score 7):

`ouput.json` file is kind of a metadata file for your generated APK. This file is generated due to various reasons. I have found some of them, which might not list all of the use cases, but here's the list:

1. Generated when `Generate Signed APK` is executed
2. Generated for `AndroidManifest.xml` file under

   ```
   {module}/build/intermediates/manifest/androidTest/debug/ouput.json
   ```
3. It is **not** generated for Unit tests, but only generated for AndroidTests (which depends on Android framework to be executed)
4. The file `output.json` generated for `AndroidManifest.xml` at above specified location is slightly different from the one generated for **APK** as you have mentioned.
5. As you can see the properties described by `output.json` file is very similar to the properties that we usually specify in our `build.gradle` file, so it must be used & required for build process to work successfully (or it might be getting generated as a result of successful build and extracting of required properties from `build.gradle`).

Upon this, we can conclude that it surely depends upon Android framework to be generated & it is related to be describing the details/info about the **APK** or **Manifest** file.

- I have personally tried to Google & find a proper answer to this even on Android Developers website, but it seems nothing is documented about this file in detail.
- I have checked several projects on GitHub & checked `.gitignore` file for the same, I couldn't find any of the similar `output.json` file in any of the projects hosted on GitHub. So it should be a good practice to exclude them in your commits.
- In short, this file is a descriptive file containing important metadata about project. It must be there for a reason. I would suggest you not to mess with it as we don't know what it may result in.

Comment: Good research, but I'd add that it should be safe to delete the file if you don't need it.

Comment: I think the file aim is to decompile and open code of the dex files in case  the project was lost. It has  options to  handle deobfuscation of proguard as well. Nothing else important

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio 4.0 a new file appears after succesful build (apk or aab): `app/release/output-metadata.json`. In order not to annoy with it in `Git`, just add to `<project>/.gitignore`:

```
# Metadata created after successful build.
/app/release/output-metadata.json
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who want to disable this feature, here is my trick.
It simply delete `output.json` after generation.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.assemble.doLast {
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name
        def outputPath = ""

        // If you use separated output path for both condition.
        if (buildType == "debug") {
            outputPath = "${buildDir}/outputs/apk"
        }
        if (buildType == "release") {
            outputPath = "${rootDir}/apk"
        }
        println "outputPath:" + outputPath

        delete "${outputPath}/yourFlavor1/${buildType}/output.json"
        delete "${outputPath}/yourFlavor2/${buildType}/output.json"
        delete "${outputPath}/yourFlavor.../${buildType}/output.json"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In response to the elaborate answer by @wonsuc, you can have gradle remove the file upon a successful build by adding the following code to the `android` section:

```
android {
    ...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                delete "${output.outputFile.parent}/output*.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe change this to `${output.outputFile.parent}/output-metadata.json` since AS 4.0

Comment: @rubo77 Why not output*.json to future proof it and still support older IDEs?

Comment: Sure, if someone can't test this, they can update this answer

Answer (score -1):

With previous versions of Android Studio, I had attempted to automatically name the output apk based on the output of `git describe`. However, while "Syncing Project with Gradle Files" Android Studio would run the gradle script once and capture the build config, including the output filename, and then assume that every build would continue to use the same name.

So whenever I created a new commit, the actual output filename would change. But Android Studio would either install the old version or fail if it had been cleaned up.

I believe that output.json has been added to allow Android Studio to load everything it needs to know about the last build, even if you have customised your gradle script to change something in an unexpected way.

This change isn't specifically mentioned in the gradle plugin release notes (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-0-0). Though they did make a bunch of drastic changes for performance reasons. It makes sense to me that they would prefer to run less of your gradle script when syncing. Instead capturing information about the build outputs directly from the build process.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the purpose of the file and possibly the entire build process as a whole. It sounds as though you placed your code to rename the file in the wrong place or did not make it dynamic.

Comment: I don't know why you think I'm wrong, be specific. FYI this is where I'm currently setting the output filename; https://github.com/servalproject/serval_chat/blob/4a6254d1d53664c9a481c9fefee1239bf148d350/app/build.gradle#L202 and that works just fine with the latest Android Studio. As I said above, attempting to do something similar with previous versions would result in the wrong apk being installed. Anyway, I've clarified my answer slightly to explain when Android Studio used to run your gradle script.

Comment: I am not sure if you are automating an install or just incorrectly labeling a build, but it sounds like something you didn't configure correctly. If you are generating a build based on the commit, you need to have a new commit to generate a new file. You will also need to make sure any sort of install you perform also updates the commit reference so it will locate the right file. None of this actually relies on the `output.json` file. It would be how you coded the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I use git describe to generate the version name, and then set the output apk filename based on that name so I can easily archive it. My point is that when you "Run" / "Debug" from within Android Studio, the gradle build is run. The new version of the gradle plugin generates output.json with the actual output filename that was written. This is then read back in by Android Studio so it can identify the file to install & debug. Whereas previous versions of Android Studio would assume that the output filename had not changed since the previous gradle sync.

Comment: And I'm suggesting that this change was done mostly for performance reasons, as stated in the release notes, to simplify the gradle sync process. With the side effect that Android Studio doesn't have to assume anything about what the build will output, it can simply read the json file and know for certain what happened.

Comment: There was definitely something wrong with your particular configuration that was likely resolved by the update. I suggest opening a new question if you are confused about how Android Studio and gradle function. The comments of this one aren't really the place for that.

Comment: I'm not confused about how Android Studio and gradle function. I don't know what you find confusing about my explanation of why this json file exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168928/discussion-between-jeremy-lakeman-and-loungekatt).

Answer (score -2):

I add `../../` to the beginning of the `outputFileName`, and the APK file is put into the `output` folder

```
android{
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            output.outputFileName =   "../../output_name.apk"
        }
    }
}
```