# what is json file along with apk android studio 3.0

Tags: android, json, android-studio, apk, android-studio-3.0

I am currently using android studio version 3.0 (stable). When I generate my project's apk file, **I found json file also along with apk file**. I could not understand the purpose of this file nor get any enough guidance from internet. Can anyone please guide me the purpose of this file and what to do with this json file ? **Should I needed to upload json along with my project's file to google play store** or just simply publish my app without json file. Screen short is given below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si3nN.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the <module>/release/output.json generated by Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202176/what-is-the-module-release-output-json-generated-by-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about that json file. It's just showing the different properties of the generated APK, e.g:

- versionCode
- packageId
- minSdkVersion
- ...

It is useful when you have some different flavors of your app, to have them localised when the apk's are generated.
You don't need that file to upload your app to GooglePlay, is just for your information.