# Output.json is generated when building APK in Android Studio. Do I need to copy both on my device in order to make the app work?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im very new to Android developing and software developing in general.

The project Im currently working on is an Android based app with user registration/login and displaying user data after logging in, which works fine so far on my emualted device (Genymotion, I don't have an Intel CPU).

Today I decided to try the app on a real device and clicked on "Build APK(s)" in Android Studio, latest version. I noticed two files were generated in .\app\build\outputs\apk\debug.
The apk and output.json.

I use Firebase for the authentication/registration process as well as for storing user data in a realtime database.

Do I need both files on my real device? The APK and the output.json?
It seems like it doesn't work without the output.json on my real device.

How would that work if I should decide to deploy the app in the play store or, more realistically, share it with friends?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: plug your phone into your computer, and click the play button to load it on the device. so, if u built the apk, then u can use adb to install it. use google to learn more. when you send it off to google play store you just use the apk.

Comment: You don't need `output.json` to run the app. It is merely an artifact generated by Android Studio See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202176/what-is-the-module-release-output-json-generated-by-android-studio

Comment: Thank you guys for answering. I have seen the link Frank provided before asking, decided to still ask because I actually had the APK on my phone and it didn't work as in the emulator. Only when I copied the output.json file it worked the way it should. I was able to register (which took 30 seconds on my phone/no time on emulator), login and see the user data after logging in, but the data was not shown in the Firebase database. This might need some googling. Anyway, thank you guys alot!